# Is an NTFS partition containing valuable data safe on a Linux machine?

Tags: hard-drive, filesystems, ntfs

I have a machine running Ubuntu. The hard-disk (size 600 GB) contains an NTFS partition (size 300 GB) with intensive read/write operations on it. 
**Considering NTFS is not a native Linux file system, is my data safe from corruption?**

** The NTFS partition (from an older Win7 installation) is mounted permanently. I use it as regular disk space.

Comment: The Linux NTFS driver has been stable for over a decade.  Its as safe as its going to be. Since it is an unofficial implementation its not 100% safe.

Comment: The major danger to using NTFS on Linux is the lack of file-system maintenance tools (eg chkdsk) so its a good idea to periodically scan the filesystem for issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an Ubuntu (9.04, maybe) with ext3 and a disk with NTFS for a couple of years and didn't have a problem using the Linux NTFS driver. However, there was much more read than write operations. Basically, most of the time it was read and around 10% of the operations was write.